# Python seemingly not reading from text file

Tags: python, printing, lines

```
files = []
with open("[...].log", "a+") as posshell:
    for line in files:
        print(line)
        posshell_files.append(line)
```

I have no clue. It prints nothing. The array is empty. I've tried grabbing every null character and removing them in case it's UTF16 -> open as UTF8, didn't work.

Comment: If you want to read and write use `r+`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Please do remove information from your question, people have taken time to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the incorrect second argument to the `open` call to read the file in this way:

```
posshell_files = []
with open("posshell.log", "r") as posshell:
    for line in posshell:
        print(line)
        posshell_files.append(line)
```

According to the Python docs for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), `'r'` if the default flag for reading while `'a+'` is for reading and writing but you will have to do so in a different manner:

```
with open("posshell.log","a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/3282436 for a pretty good explanation of file modes

Comment: This worked but my understanding is that I was using one that should be a catch all. edit; thanks for the link

Comment: @DylanMoore see edits above for more detail, but the link from 0x5453 is a nice summary

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('posshell.log') as p:
    content = p.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```